# Sharepoint 2013 - create a column that contain current date in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am very new to sharepoint,
currently i am working to create a column that contains current date in sharepoint list.
the problem is i want the date automatically change based on today's date.

for example,
today is 19/12/2014,
and when it comes to tomorrow it will change automatically to 20/12/2015, and next.

Answer (score 0):

It is one of the standard choices, if you choose column type "Date and time"- see the defaults section at the bottom.

Comment: hi naivists, I've tried the default section by set it to today's date, unfortunately when it comes to the next day it wont change to tomorrow's date. i want it to be dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried the "Today's date" option in this selector? http://en.share-gate.com/~/media/Sharegate/Images/2014/February/start-learn-sp-3/cadre_image4.ashx

Comment: yes I have, but didn't work the way i expect, it still set as today's date when it comes to tomorrow. http://postimg.org/image/cfo58b9gv/

Answer (score 0):

You can add formula

```
=[Today]
```

if you have bad day thats mean you have messes up with servers time services but you can hitfix that:

```
=[Today] + 1
```

but it will only work after editing the item (I think), so programically solution is timerjob that run everyday and set last day dates to next date

Comment: yes you are rite, it's impossible everyday i need to run it manually, the solution is i need to create a workflow to trigger a change on the date column, but there must be an event like create item or edit item, maybe the only solution i have to implement js into my sharepoint.